# Pygame key presses not working the same as guides

Tags: python, pygame, exit, python-3.8

I followed a snake game tutorial but for some reason I can't get the `QUIT` to match:

```py
class Game:

    ...

    def handle_keys(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            pressed = pg.key.get_pressed()
            if event.type == QUIT or pressed[QUIT]:
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if pressed[pg.K_UP]:
                    self.snake.turn(self.UP)
                elif pressed[pg.K_DOWN]:
                    self.snake.turn(self.DOWN)
                elif pressed[pg.K_LEFT]:
                    self.snake.turn(self.LEFT)
                elif pressed[pg.K_RIGHT]:
                    self.snake.turn(self.RIGHT)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.clock.tick(10)
            self.handle_keys()
```

The snake moves fine but the QUIT button doesn't seem to be working no matter which method I try or even a combination of both as shown above. I'm on the latest Ubuntu 20.04 version not sure if that makes a difference. I noticed the values for `event.TYPE` and `pressed[QUIT]` are completely different from `pg.QUIT` and `pg.locals.QUIT`. This is my first attempt at pygame as well just not sure why not getting the same output as the guide I'm following.

## EDIT:

None of the solutions I find online are working nor the ones "related" or "suggested" below. I'm just going to switch to Unity3D after struggling with this for over a week now.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try

```py
if event.type == pg.QUIT:
```

removing the `or pressed[QUIT]`.
Don't use `pg.locals.QUIT`, try `pg.QUIT`.

Comment: I tried that way as well. In the code above is just showing an attempt at both combination together.

Comment: and the use of pg.locals.QUIT was a desperate attempt :)

Comment: i see, hmmmm, idk what else then

Comment: yeah, still not working today so just going to download unity3d

Answer (score 1):

I added a few lines of code to your code, and this works:

```
import pygame as pg
import sys

pg.init()
wn = pg.display.set_mode((600, 600))

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.UP = 0
        self.DOWN = 0
        self.LEFT = 0
        self.RIGHT = 0
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        
    def turn(self, number):
        pass
    
    def handle_keys(self):
        for event in pg.event.get():
            pressed = pg.key.get_pressed()
            if event.type == pg.QUIT or pressed[pg.QUIT]:
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if pressed[pg.K_UP]:
                    self.snake.turn(self.UP)
                elif pressed[pg.K_DOWN]:
                    self.snake.turn(self.DOWN)
                elif pressed[pg.K_LEFT]:
                    self.snake.turn(self.LEFT)
                elif pressed[pg.K_RIGHT]:
                    self.snake.turn(self.RIGHT)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.clock.tick(10)
            self.handle_keys()
            pg.display.update()

game = Game()
game.run()
```

I changed the `QUIT` to `pg.QUIT`.

Comment: not working on my machine still. It's a very simple thing that's annoying me for not working at this point I'm just downloading unity3d

Comment: @MarcoFernandes Perhaps uninstall and then reinstall pygame? The pygame you have now might be not fully installed.

Comment: I've tried that already as well. Including installing it via `apt` and `pip`. I tried setting up a completely new Ubuntu environment virtually to test and still not working. At this point I'm assuming it's my laptop's manufacturers keyboard settings